# Android: How to correctly use "CalendarAlerts" to display unique message in Alarms

Tags: android, alarmmanager, android-calendar, reminders, alerts

I have created some events and stored the data in sqlite table but not the system calendar. However, i would like to have an alert/reminder for these events, which is similar to other events that stored in the system.

With reference to the code below, the details of the event are put in the "CalendarAlerts" table and in the broadcast receiver, the alertCursor is used to find the event data with start time close to the current time.

The code worked well if the event is stored in the system with a "long" eventID. But when i try to put data of my sqlite event in "CalendarAlerts" with a "string" eventID. It shows that the data is inserted into the table successfully but i would not query back the result in the "Alert Receiver" class.

Searched google for a while and it seems that not many people are talking on the topic of "CalendarAlerts". Great if anyone would share the experience on this issue.

Setting the AlarmManager

```
Uri alertUri = CalendarAlerts.CONTENT_URI;
long alarmMillis = (long) mStart - (long)(min*60*1000);

ContentValues alertValues =AlertUtils.makeContentValues(eventIdentifier,mStart, mEnd,alarmMillis, 0);
context.getContentResolver().insert(alertUri, alertValues);

public static ContentValues makeContentValues(String eventId, long begin, long end,
        long alarmTime, int minutes) {
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(CalendarAlerts.EVENT_ID, eventId);
    values.put(CalendarAlerts.BEGIN, begin);
    values.put(CalendarAlerts.END, end);
    values.put(CalendarAlerts.ALARM_TIME, alarmTime);
    long currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    values.put(CalendarAlerts.CREATION_TIME, currentTime);
    values.put(CalendarAlerts.RECEIVED_TIME, 0);
    values.put(CalendarAlerts.NOTIFY_TIME, 0);
    values.put(CalendarAlerts.STATE, CalendarAlerts.STATE_SCHEDULED);
    values.put(CalendarAlerts.MINUTES, minutes);
    return values;
}
```

AlertReceiver.java

```
Cursor alertCursor = cr.query(CalendarAlerts.CONTENT_URI, ALERT_PROJECTION,
            (ACTIVE_ALERTS_SELECTION + currentMillis), ACTIVE_ALERTS_SELECTION_ARGS,
            ACTIVE_ALERTS_SORT);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code which works for me :

```
ContentResolver cr = getActivity().getContentResolver();
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

values.put(CalendarContract.Events.DTSTART, startMillis);
values.put(CalendarContract.Events.TITLE, title);
values.put(CalendarContract.Events.DESCRIPTION, "description");

TimeZone timeZone = TimeZone.getDefault();
values.put(CalendarContract.Events.EVENT_TIMEZONE, timeZone.getID());

// default calendar
values.put(CalendarContract.Events.CALENDAR_ID, 1);

//for one hour
values.put(CalendarContract.Events.DURATION, "+P1H");
values.put(CalendarContract.Events.HAS_ALARM, 1);

// cr.delete(CalendarContract.Events.CONTENT_URI, null,null);
// insert event to calendar
Uri uri = cr.insert(CalendarContract.Events.CONTENT_URI, values);
```

Comment: So u actually put the sqlite event into the system to make it work? But how  would u identify the event without getting the eventID?

Comment: no identify the event without getting the event id ,event id  is unique,yes work for sqlite event into device